# Filter Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

**Disclaimer:** I did not create this model. I know it's not a good one and it should be refactored. But I can't change it and I have to work with it. Also, sorry if I made any grammar mistake, english is not my first language.

I have this (simplified) model, where an Event has a group, and this group has many users.

```
class Event():
    clients_group = models.ForeignKey("ClientsGroup")

class ClientsGroup():
    group_name = models.CharField()
    clients = models.ManyToManyField("Client")

class Client():
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

When a user logs in, I need to get a list of events that this user is related to.

I tried this:

```
list_of_events = Event.objects.filter(clients_group__clients__user__username=logged_in_user.username)
```

But I get an empty list.

Comment: Do smaller querysets work? For example, what does `Client.objects.filter(user__username=logged_in_user.username)` return? How about `ClientsGroup.objects.filter(clients__user__username=logged_in_user.username` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Your client field in the ClientsGroup model is incorrect. It should be

```
clients = models.ManyToManyField("Client")
```

**not**

```
clients = models.ManyToMany("Client")
```

When you fix that, I think it should work. Double check that your models do actually have objects in them and that they link to eachother.

### Futher Debugging

If it still doesn't work after changing the field name, try splitting up your query to debug. For example you could the query into two seperate queries

```
target_client = Client.objects.get(user=logged_in_user)
list_of_events = Event.objects.filter(clients_group__clients=target_client)
```

From here you can figure out which queries are working and which aren't.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was a mistake that I made when I create the question. In the actual code it's ManyToManyField

Comment: Ok. Have you tried splitting the queries up and seeing if you can at least get the Client?